# iPhone: Formatting Json params using third party parser

Tags: iphone, json

I want to create JSON object params for example below. I had worked on iOS 5 devices and could able to achieve this using NSJSONSerialization API. For example, i created a generic function "makeJSONObject()" and using for it.

```
Sample Payload 1:
{
  token: "kjsdfjl23kkj23kk"
  entries: [
    {
      "title": "welcome",
      "name": "myself",
      "date": "2012-02-06T00:14:20Z",
    },{
      "title": "Hi",
      "name": "martin",
      "date": "2012-02-06T00:14:20Z",
    }
  ]
}

Sample Payload 2:
{
  "email" : "me@company.com",
  "password" : "pswrd"
}
```

**CODE:**

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [appDelegate makeJSONObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: emailStr, passwordStr, nil] :[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"email", @"password", nil] ];

-(NSString *) makeJSONObject :(NSArray *)objects :(NSArray *)keys
{
    NSString *theBodyString = NULL;

    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    //NSLog(@"data: %@", data);

    NSError *writeError = nil;    
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];


    theBodyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    return theBodyString;
}
```

But, i want to support now for 4.0 devices, and i can't use NSJSONSerialization API now. I may have to use SBJson or something like that i guess and i have no idea. Could someone help me how can i modify my generic function above to make use of 
SBJson or some third party parser classes?

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&json_data=%@",[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"listInvoice\":{\"client_id\":\"\",\"date_from\":\"\",\"date_to\":\"\",\"invoice_number\":\"\",\"invoice_record_status\":\"\",\"invoice_status\":\"\",\"page\":\"1\",\"per_page_record\":\"20\"}}"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: I have to dynamically add array of entires, so it may not help in that case. Pls look at Sample Payload 1:, which has array of entires created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try my extension for NSArray/NSDictionary for building JSON strings from these basic data types.
https://github.com/H2CO3/CarbonateJSON